# listener for <p:autocomplete> when an user clicks on an option

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I want to navigate to another page when an user clicks an option from dropdown menu of `<p:autocomplete>`, tried using the `onclick` listener of `<p:autocomplete>` but it triggers whenever I click on `<p:autocomplete>` textbox. Is there any way to achieve this by using javascript or using a backing bean, what listener should I use to get the required result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use ajax itemSelect event

```
 <p:autoComplete ...>  
     <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.handleSelect}" />  
 </p:autoComplete>
```

This will call the handleSelect method in your bean whenever an item is selected

You may also look at [primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/autoCompleteSelect.jsf)

Comment: `handleSelect` is of void type, so I can't return any string for navigation, like I do for `action` attribute of other JSF components. Is there any alternative?

Comment: You can redirect from ajax requests, please see http://weblogs.java.net/blog/driscoll/archive/2009/05/redirecting_fro.html